# boost spirit repetition parser behaves unexpectedly

Tags: boost-spirit-qi

using boost 1.57 spirit::qi under windows 7
I'm working on an ipv6 parser and must be misunderstanding how repetition parser directives work.
Given the following (simplified)

```
ipv6part = repeat(1, 4)[xdigit];

ipv6address =
-(repeat(1,4)[ipv6part >> lit(':')] >> ipv6part) >> 
    lit("::") >> ipv6part >> lit(':') >> ipv6part
| ...
```

I would expect to match the following addresses:

> 1111:5555::ffff:eeee
>   1111:2222:5555::ffff:eeee
>   1111:2222:3333:5555::ffff:eeee
>   1111:2222:3333:4444:5555::ffff:eeee

however, when i test the only match is the maximum from the repeat clause:

> 1111:2222:3333:4444:5555::ffff:eeee

Now, explicitly specifying each combination matches all cases:

```
ipv6address =
-(repeat(1)[ipv6part >> lit(':')] >> ipv6part) >> 
    lit("::") >> ipv6part >> lit(':') >> ipv6part
| -(repeat(2)[ipv6part >> lit(':')] >> ipv6part) >> 
    lit("::") >> ipv6part >> lit(':') >> ipv6part
| -(repeat(3)[ipv6part >> lit(':')] >> ipv6part) >> 
    lit("::") >> ipv6part >> lit(':') >> ipv6part
| -(repeat(4)[ipv6part >> lit(':')] >> ipv6part) >> 
    lit("::") >> ipv6part >> lit(':') >> ipv6part
| ...
```

but this seems silly; it can't be right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it appears the **repeat(N,M)** doesn't backtrack when the remainder of the parse fails.
so, if the input is **11:22:55::ff:ee**, the repeat part takes **11:22:55:** leaving **:ff:ee** which fails.

I'm not quite sure from the docs if this is intended behavior, but a workaround is to not grab a colon as the final character in the repeat, which avoids the problem of splitting the **'::'**, like this

```
ipv6address =
-(ipv6part >> repeat(1,4)[lit(':') >> ipv6part]) >> lit("::") >> ipv6part >> lit(':') >> ipv6part
```